# How to set the width of a text input field in a form to a percentage of page width?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, mobile

I am trying to set the width of a text input field as a percentage of total page width, as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="url" NAME="otherSite" size="70%" value=""/>
```

This doesn't seem to work.  It seems I can specify the width of an input field only in absolute terms.

Short of going to javascript, is there any simple way?  I am trying to have it look good both on desktop and mobile, where the windows are likely to be of very different size.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the size of input fields be set to percent values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14945309/can-the-size-of-input-fields-be-set-to-percent-values)

Answer (score 6):

Use the `style` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="url" NAME="otherSite" style="width:70%" value=""/>
```

You also might want to read up on [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) (Cascading Style Sheets).

Comment: @RobinDavies This jsfiddle suggests otherwise. http://jsfiddle.net/Kwf98/ I tested in the latest Chrome and in IE 11. Can you create a jsfiddle that demonstrates where you're seeing this not work?

Comment: Sorry. Worked fine after all. It was mistake in enclosing layout. :-P (would delete the comment if I could).