# Can the size of input fields be set to percent values?

Tags: html, css, input

I am unable to create an input field which covers 80% of the width of the browser window while being centered.

```
<input style="margin-right:10%; margin-left:10%;" size="100%">
```

only works when the browser is maximized.

Comment: do you have `html {width:100%}` in your CSS?

Comment: Have you tried `width: 100%` ?

Comment: how you set the with of that input? show your code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="text" id="url" NAME="otherSite" style="width:70%" value=""/>
```